# Zend_form and jquery

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zend-form

I want this function to run when I submit a form..

```
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Button('submit');
$submit->setAttrib('onclick', '---what should go here?---');
```

Client-side script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('href');
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();
        $('#mask').css({
            'width':maskWidth,
            'height':maskHeight
        });
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
        $(id).fadeIn(2000); 
    });
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });         
});
```

Comment: Right now it appears that function runs when the document has finished loading?  Do you want to keep that behavior or run that when the submit button is pushed instead, or do you want it to run in both cases?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use onclick when you are using jQuery

For example, consider the HTML taken from http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

The event handler can be bound to the form:

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});
```

The form can be generated via Zend_Form itself , but this is just for demonstration.